# Sample lower bound for binary classification in Linear Discriminant Analysis?

Tags: classification, references, sample-size, discriminant-analysis, mathematical-statistics

Below is a description of this problem:

---

Suppose the label $Y\in\{1,0\}$ in binary classification satisfies $\Pr[Y=1]=\Pr[Y=0]=\frac{1}{2}$, and $p(X|Y=1)=\mathcal{N}(\mu_1,\Sigma)$, $p(X|Y=0)=\mathcal{N}(\mu_0,\Sigma)$. Here $\mu_1, \mu_0 \in \mathbb{R}^p$, $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$, where $p$ is the dimension.

To train a classifier I use $n$ samples $(X_1, Y_1), (X_2, Y_2), \dots, (X_n, Y_n)$.

For *any* classifier $C$ (not restricted to LDA, logistic regression, SVM, etc.), what is minimum number of samples I need so that the expected 0-1 error of the classifier is smaller than $\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon$ for some small $\epsilon>0$? That is: 
$$
\Pr[C(X) \neq Y] \leq \frac{1}{2}-\epsilon
$$

The sample lower bound should be given in terms of $\mu_1$, $\mu_0$, $\Sigma$, $\epsilon$.

---

Has anybody studied the sample lower bound for this problem?

It seems that people have studied sample complexity of estimating the parameters ([ref1](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~ecprice/papers/gaussians.pdf)), but there doesn't seem to be much regarding the sample complexity for classification, which does not necessarily need parameters to be correctly estimated.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the prior on labels is flat: fifty fifty and the question is how many training examples are needed for an error to be below 1/2-$\epsilon$. Is an error of 1/2 a random classifier?

Comment: @xeon That's correct.

Comment: This is interesting! My intuition say that to kick a random classifier (e.g. random parameter values for logistic regression) out of 1/2, you need only two points: one from each class. You sample one point from $p(X|Y=1)$ and one point from $p(X|Y=0)$. How to reason using more solid evidence, still need to think about it.